# Qiskit - Simpler way to create a Hamiltonian

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I am looking for an efficient way to create a Hamiltonian in Qiskit.

Following are my desired input and outputs

> input: 'ZZI'

> output: Z^Z^I, where Z and I are operators.

Here is how I am doing it right now:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.opflow import X, Y, Z, I   
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE

weights = [i for i in range(1,4)]

hamiltonian = weights[0]*(Z^Z^I) + weights[1]*(Z^I^Z) + weights[2]*(I^Z^Z)


num_qubits = hamiltonian.num_qubits
ansatz = TwoLocal(num_qubits, ['ry','rz'], 'cx', 'linear', reps=1, insert_barriers=True)

qi = QuantumInstance(Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator'))
    
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=100)
vqe = VQE(ansatz, optimizer=optimizer, quantum_instance=qi)
result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(hamiltonian)
```

If I have to run the same experiment on a 4 qubit, I need to redo the `hamiltonian` again. For example it would be:

```
hamiltonian = weights[0]*(Z^Z^I^I) + weights[1]*(Z^I^Z^I) + weights[2]*(Z^I^I^Z) + weights[3]*(I^Z^Z^I) + weights[4]*(I^Z^I^Z) + + weights[4]*(I^I^Z^Z)
```

This option is not scalable when I have a 15 qubit circuit. I would really appreciate it if anyone can guide me in a way that I can build a scalable `hamiltonian`.

I tried the following method and no luck:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator, Pauli
hamiltonian = Operator(Pauli(label='ZZI')) + Operator(Pauli(label='ZIZ')) + Operator(Pauli(label='IZZ'))
```

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [PauliSumOp](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.PauliSumOp.html) to do (for example) the following:

```
from qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops import PauliSumOp
paulis  =  ['IZ', 'XZ', 'YZ', 'ZZ', 'XX']
weights  =  [1,2,3,4,5]
pauli_op = [([pauli,weight]) for pauli,weight in zip(paulis,weights)]
hamiltonian = PauliSumOp.from_list([ op for op in pauli_op ])
```

You can then pass this `hamiltonian` object into the VQE instance like you did.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much!